# Why does Radix sort has larger number of instructions than Quick sort in C?

Tags: algorithm

I set 2 functions of sorting algorithms, radix sort and quick sort in C
But when I check those fuctions with gdb, it turns out that quick sort has smaller number of instructions than radix sort. And feels like even faster...
As i know, Radix sort is the fastest sorting algorithm. 
Belows are my sorting codes from wiki.
1. Quick sort

```
void q_sort(int numbers[], int left, int right)
 {
   if(left == right) return;
   int pivot, l_hold, r_hold;
   l_hold = left;
   r_hold = right;
   pivot = numbers[left];

   while (left < right)
   {
     while ((numbers[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
       right--;

     if (left != right)
     {
       numbers[left] = numbers[right];
       left++;
     }

     while ((numbers[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
       left++;

     if (left != right)
     {
       numbers[right] = numbers[left];
       right--;
     }
   }

   numbers[left] = pivot;
   pivot = left;
   left = l_hold;
   right = r_hold;

   if (left < pivot)
     q_sort(numbers, left, pivot-1);
   if (right > pivot)
     q_sort(numbers, pivot+1, right);
 }
```

2.Radix sort

```
/**
 * @data  array
 * @size  the number of array
 * @p  cipher of the biggest number
 * @k  notation( in case of decimal, it is 10)

 */
void rxSort(int *data, int size, int p, int k) {
     int *counts,
     *temp;
     int index, pval, i, j, n;
     if ( (counts = (int*) malloc(k * sizeof(int))) == NULL )
          return;
     if ( (temp = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int))) == NULL )
          return;
     for (n=0; n<p; n++) {
          for (i=0; i<k; i++)
               counts[i] = 0; // initialize

          // n:0 => 1,  1 => 10, 2 => 100
          pval = (int)pow((double)k, (double)n);
          for (j=0; j<size; j++) {
               // if the number is  253
               // n:0 => 3,  1 => 5, 2 => 2
               index = (int)(data[j] / pval) % k;
               counts[index] = counts[index] + 1;
          }
          for (i=1; i<k; i++) {
               counts[i] = counts[i] + counts[i-1];
          }
          for (j=size-1; j>=0; j--) {
               index = (int)(data[j] / pval) % k;
               temp[counts[index] -1] = data[j];
               counts[index] = counts[index] - 1;
          }

          memcpy(data, temp, size * sizeof(int));
     }
}
```

There are some restrictions as belows
1. The size of array should be set to 256.
2. the number is range from 0 ~ 64.
3. It operates four times with different arrays.

When I tested, I set the size of array as 50
Then, the number of instrunctions
Radix : 15030
Quick : 7484
Quick wins...T_T.. so sad about Radix... is it true that Quick sort is faster?

Comment: It seems you may be misinterpreting asymptotic complexity...

Comment: I'm algorithm virgin, actually. If you explain what that means, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Your sample size is way too small - try sorting 50 million values instead. Also, there's no one-to-one relationship between the number of instructions executed and the performance. How did you determine the number of instructions executed, by the way?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError with gdb & set break point & and some kinde of gdb instructions

Comment: `it turns out that  quick sort  has smaller number of instructions than  quick sort.` Oha. Never invest brain cycles into timing results below five seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quicksort is, generally, the best choice you have when sorting an array, especially when you don't have information on the range of the numbers and the array is pretty big. That's because qsort has an expected time complexity proportional to the size of its input times the logarithm of that size, O(nlogn), which is the best you can have with an algorithm based on comparisons. Moreover, it has a small hidden constant factor and it sorts in place. Radix sort doesn't sort with comparisons, you need to have some information about the size of the input (n) and the average number of digits per number(k), because its time complexity is proportional to k*n.

In your case you have quite a small array to do tests on, so any observable difference between the behaviour of the two algorithms is asymptotically irrelevant. Quicksort wins because, as said, it has a small constant factor of operations hidden in that O(nlogn). If you try to run Insertion sort and Merge sort on a small array, despite InsSort having O(n^2) and MergeSort O(nlogn) in the worst case, there is a great chance that Insertion sort will be quicker, for the same reason as above.
But rest assure that if you try them on an array of 10^8 numbers, the result will change a lot.
Also keep in mind there is no such a thing as **the best sorting algorithm**, you just have to see each time which of them suits better the nature of your problem. :)